# Remove space between consecutive fbox commands

Tags: spacing, boxes, csv

I type several fbox commands and for some reason the boxes are separated with small spaces:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-15mm}

\raggedright

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}

\end{document}
```

My first thought was that this is due to justification. But then I left aligned the contents and the "problem" is still there.

I want to remove space between these fboxes: both vertical and horizontal (shown on the screenshot with red arrows).

**Edit**:

The original problem is to generate badges with datatool. I have a badge template and I generate it many times from a csv file using datatool. The problem is that badges are a little bit apart from each other so I would have to cut them out manually later.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{&}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-15mm}


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
NAME&TITLE
Name1 & Title1
Name2 & Title2
Name3 & Title3
Name4 & Title4
Name5 & Title5
Name6 & Title6
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*
{data}
{\NAME=NAME,\TITLE=TITLE}
{
  \noindent
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][55mm]{90mm}
      \vspace{11mm}

      \centering
      \vfill
      {\bf \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\textrm{\NAME}\par}
      \vfill

      \large\itshape\TITLE

      \vspace{5mm}

    \end{minipage}}
}

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

**Edit**:

In case one is going to use two-sided badges -- one would want to have same name written twice, as is allows to bend the badge and have the same name on both sides. In this case one might use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
NAME&AFFILIATION
Name1 & Title1
Name2 & Title2
Name3 & Title3
Name4 & Title4
Name5 & Title5
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{&}
\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% 4 per in a column:
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

% % 5 per in a column:
% \usepackage[a4paper,top=0.27cm,bottom=0.1cm,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\par
% \offinterlineskip
\noindent % <- Outside the loop
\DTLforeach*{data}{\NAME=NAME,\AFFILIATION=AFFILIATION}
{% <- Spurious space was here
  \allowbreak % <- Added
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][55mm]{90mm}
      \vspace{11mm}

      \centering
      \vfill
      {\bf \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\textrm{\NAME}\par}
      \vfill

      \large\itshape\AFFILIATION

      \vspace{5mm}

    \end{minipage}}% <- Spurious space was here
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][55mm]{90mm}
      \vspace{11mm}

      \centering
      \vfill
      {\bf \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\textrm{\NAME}\par}
      \vfill

      \large\itshape\AFFILIATION

      \vspace{5mm}

    \end{minipage}}% <- Spurious space was here
}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: what about using a table?

Comment: @Guido: the original problem is to generate badges with datatool. I have a badge template and I generate it many times from a csv file using datatool. The problem is that badges are a little bit apart from each other so I would have to cut them out manually later.

Comment: There are spurious blank spaces in your code producing the undesired horizontal separation. You should have mentioned the original problem since the beginning!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I thought it was too detailed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spurious spaces. I also removed `\noindent` from the loop, put it outside, and put `\allowbreak` before any `\fbox`. With `\offinterlineskip` all goes well. If you want to have another things in the document, you should enclose everything in a group `\begingroup .. \endgroup`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{&}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{-15mm}


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
NAME&TITLE
Name1 & Title1
Name2 & Title2
Name3 & Title3
Name4 & Title4
Name5 & Title5
Name6 & Title6
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\par
\offinterlineskip
\noindent % <- Outside the loop
\DTLforeach*{data}{\NAME=NAME,\TITLE=TITLE}
{% <- Spurious space was here
  \allowbreak % <- Added
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][55mm]{90mm}
      \vspace{11mm}

      \centering
      \vfill
      {\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\NAME\par}
      \vfill

      \large\itshape\TITLE

      \vspace{5mm}

    \end{minipage}}% <- Spurious space was here
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your answer was I was doing my last edit after seeing what the OP really wanted. I think now my answer is utterly superfluous and will delete it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I think you shouldn't delete answer with 4 upvotes. It shows that it is interesting to users.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Beat you by a few seconds, I see :) I think the idea of taking `\noindent` outside and putting `\allowbreak` inside is good. You can add it to your answer if you want. I will remove mine, since yours is already upvoted. Well, it seems mine is accepted, I won't remove it. But you shouldn't delete it, IMO.

Comment: @Manuel No, it's OK. You answered fine and first, well deserved green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy for the collumns space. Use `%` at the end of line to remove any extra space. To remove the vertical space, you have to use negative space to move the box up. (I'll edit soon)

```
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}%
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}\\
```

Comment: This makes four of them too long for a page. Is it possible to enable line folding (text wrap) with this solution?

Comment: You solution sill leaves vertical space between fboxes.

Comment: @Adobe, edited.

Comment: `\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}%
\fbox{text text text text text text text text text text text}\\[-0.1\normalbaselineskip]` seems to be working.